# Can "suru" be also added to japanese verbs?

Tags: grammar, nuances, verbs

I thought that "suru" was used with english verbs to create japanese verbs 
(ie ドライブする) or with japanese nouns to create japanese verbs 
(ie denwa suru  電話する)

Can "suru" be also added to japanese verbs? If so, what's the purpose of adding "suru" to a word that is already a verb. For example, 運転, according to Google translator (which I dont know if it works properly) both 運転 and 運転する means to drive. Is this so? If so is there any nuance in both?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify you're claiming 運転 by itself (without する) is a verb???

Comment: I'm not claiming that Google does. I just updated the post btw.

Comment: Regardless of whether the translation is correct, it doesn't look like a claim about the lexical class of 運転 in Japanese to me.  If someone asked you to translate ○○のことが好き into English, you'd probably use a verb to translate 好き, but that doesn't mean 好き itself is a verb.

Comment: @snailboat I second this. There are a lot of words that could be considered noun-class, or adjective-class, that would be expressed in a verb format in other languages, where in Japanese they are descriptions of a state of being, instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

運転, by itself, is a noun, just like most of these 2-kanji words. The construction is thus the same as with 電話する, you add する to the noun to turn it into a verb.

**NEVER** use Google translate as a dictionary. Instead, use a dictionary, such as https://jisho.org/search/%E9%81%8B%E8%BB%A2

Although, I must add that Google translate translates this correctly for me, i.e. into "operation" or "driving".

Comment: you have to check Google's suggestion box to see what I said

Comment: I did, your problem is that you are translating Japanese to Spanish, via Google Translate. If you are going to use it, at the very least, translate to English, **always** to/from English. The problem is that Google translate only has language pairs with English, so whatever you translate, it will always pass by English and be distorted twice instead of just once.

Comment: @Pablo  I find that jisho.org is much more reliable than Google is.

Comment: Surely this answer is missing the point of the question, which was: can suru be added to a verb. I deduce that it can. At least its respectful relation nasaru can: for example おやすみなさい